# How to download multiple files by parts(size/limit) from same directory in S3 using Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have 3 millions small files(12-15kb each) in S3 directory. I want to download 20000 files in each chunk from S3. Is there any way where I can download multiple files at once by limiting file numbers?

I tried listObjectsV2Request using multi-threading as well, but trying to find out better way to improve performance.
Also I tried using transferManager.downloadDirectory, but which is downloading complete directory causing outOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination with `ListObjectsV2`: Use `ListObjectsV2Request` for efficient pagination. AWS SDK provides the ability to paginate the listing of S3 objects in chunks, which you can leverage to list objects in manageable batches (for example, 20,000 files at a time).

Concurrent Downloads with a Custom Pool: Instead of relying solely on `TransferManager.downloadDirectory`, which tries to download an entire directory, use a combination of listing objects in batches and then downloading those batches using a custom executor service or a thread pool. This way, you have direct control over the number of concurrent downloads, thereby preventing `OutOfMemoryError` by not overloading the memory with too many concurrent threads or download tasks.

Efficient Resource Management: Ensure proper handling of resources, like closing streams and managing temporary storage effectively, to avoid memory leaks.

```
public class S3BatchDownloader {

    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "bucket-name";
    private static final String PREFIX = "directory-prefix/";
    private static final int MAX_KEYS = 20000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

        ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(BUCKET_NAME).withPrefix(PREFIX).withMaxKeys(MAX_KEYS);
        ListObjectsV2Result result;

        do {
            // List objects in batches of MAX_KEYS
            result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(req);

            // For each object in the batch, submit a download task to the executor service
            for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : result.getObjectSummaries()) {
                executorService.submit(() -> {
                    // Implement your download logic here, e.g., s3Client.getObject(...)
                    System.out.println("Downloading: " + objectSummary.getKey());
                    // Remember to handle exceptions and ensure resources are closed properly
                });
            }

            // Prepare the next request
            req.setContinuationToken(result.getNextContinuationToken());
        } while (result.isTruncated());

        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Customize Download Task: The download logic inside the executorService.submit lambda function is where you'd implement your specific download handling, perhaps using s3Client.getObject() or another method, and save the file locally.

ExecutorService Configuration: Adjust the thread pool size in Executors.newFixedThreadPool() according to your environment's capabilities and the desired concurrency level. Too many threads can lead to performance degradation or memory issues, while too few can result in underutilization of resources.
Error Handling and Resource Management: Implement robust error handling within your download tasks, and ensure that all resources (e.g., input/output streams) are properly closed to avoid memory leaks.

This approach offers a balance between performance and resource usage, allowing for scalability and control over the download process.